# How Can I Create a Customized DataGrid View in C# - Winforms Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e9ab873d56.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e9ab873d56.png)

Look at the bottom component where GroupBox is Open Work Orders. What components is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like just an ordinary `ListView`, with its `View` property set to `Details` and three `Columns` added.